# keep running a method after API returns/call ends in C#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a really time taking method which I do not want to wait for, I want to give the API response while this particular method is still running, let me know what I can use to do this, I tried to use multi-threading but it waits for all the threads to end before returning the response. Please suggest alternatives.

Comment: What response do you want to give exactly?  If the method hasn't finished running then you have no result to send back to the user.

Comment: The time taking method I am talking about is a separate method from the main method, the main method calls the time taking method, I want to give response when main method finish executing and do not want to wait for the time taking method.

Comment: As per my understanding, TAP waits for all the threads to finish executing before it responds/returns. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io) might be a good fit, supports different "job" types and easy to get going.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it looks like it could do the job, but is there anything built in to .net which I can use?

Comment: [Queued background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks), I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

See if message queues ( e.g. RabbitMQ ) are a good fit for what you need.

Answer (score -1):

Put it in a Task.Run, don't await the Task.Run.